# Creating an ArchLinux AUR Mirror possible?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, rsync, wget, mirroring

Is it possible, to mirror the AUR (Arch User Repository) like shown [here](https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Eigenen_Mirror_erstellen) for Setting up an offline AUR (mirror)? As an alternative would it be possible to use `wget` in some way?

Comment: There is a mirror in China https://aur.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/. Not sure how they achieve it.